# invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

#define initialSize 50

//Public GCC compiler-friendly macros

#define n argv[2]

using namespace std;

struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
};


int smallest(Point* p, int n);

int size = 0, max_size = initialSize;
int *A = new int[max_size];


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        int test;
        Point* p = new Point();
        smallest(p, test);

    return 0;
}

int smallest(Point *p, int n) {
return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, this should be valid syntax for C++. However I get the following compiling error:

```
test.cpp:32:20: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:23:5: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘int smallest(Point*, int*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

I am using the command: `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`

**EDIT:** Added the entire source code instead of snippets. Tried on a different environment but encountered same compiling error.

Comment: The compiler believes that `smallest` takes an `int*` as its second parameter, not `int`. Most likely, the code you've shown here is not in fact the code you are actually compiling. The code you've shown [compiles without error](http://rextester.com/OCA2667)

Comment: Prefer not to use pointers.  Declare your variable as `Point p;`.  This is C++ language not C# or Java - no need to `new` every variable.  Also, consider passing `Point` by reference.

Comment: See any C++ FAQ out there, it will explain to you why macros are evil. Further, globals are also often a cause of problems rather than a solution.

Comment: @SemyonBurov hit the nail on the head. You have `#define n argv[2]` and then `int smallest(Point* p, int n);`, which expands to `int smallest(Point* p, int argv[2]);`, which is equivalent to `int smallest(Point* p, int* argv);`. In the immortal words of Herb Sutter: ["Macros are obnoxious, smelly, sheet-hogging bedfellows"](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/063.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
#define n argv[2]
```

Second:

```
int smallest(Point* p, int n);
```

Third:

```
int test;
```

Forth:

```
smallest(p, test);
```

I don't know why you need that define, but it's definitely him cause such strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The code you post compiles correctly.

Try not using pointers:

```
int smallest(const Point& p, int value)
{
  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  int test = 15;
  Point p;
  smallest(p, test);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```