# Abusing #define notation in C++

Tags: c++

I've lately been a little worried about abusing #define notation in c++, specifically for competitive/mathematical programming.

I've been doing c++ for 3 months (so I'm a beginner). Almost ever since I started, I've used the handy

```
#define FOR(i,n) for(long (i)=0;(i)<(n);((i)++))
```

I must say it makes life much easier.

However lately I've been using

```
#define whole(x) begin(x),end(x)
```

to do things like `accumulate(whole(iVector),0)`. I think it's ok.

But now I do things like (for a knight breadth-first-search-problem).

```
#define QUICKINSERT(a,b) if(iSet.find(current+make_pair(a,b))==iSet.end()){ iQue2.push(current + make_pair(a,b)); iSet.insert(current + make_pair(a,b)); }
```

and

```
                QUICKINSERT(x,y);  
                QUICKINSERT(y,x);  
                QUICKINSERT(-x,y);  
                QUICKINSERT(-y,x);  
                QUICKINSERT(x,-y);  
                QUICKINSERT(y,-x);  
                QUICKINSERT(-x,-y);  
                QUICKINSERT(-y,-x);
```

What are the consequences if this gets carried away? And what are the alernatives (lambda functions or something)?

Comment: Macros are impossible to debug.

Comment: For the first: use range-based for loops when possible (and use `size_t` or whatever is appropriate, not `long`). For the second, use boost ranges.

Comment: Not a complete answer: (1) Avoid inventing your own syntax  ("FOR"). Modern C++ *specifically* introduced range iteration to solve the awkwardness of the old boiler plate code: `for (auto& item: vec){/* use vec element item */ }`. (2) Use inline functions for function-like macros; C++ introduced them *specifically* to avoid the downsides of function macros, foremost their lacking type safety.

Comment: Don't depend on macros as much as possible they are not safe. Depend on the compiler not the pre-processor.

Comment: 2 latter examples definitly can be implemented by functions. Why do you use macro there?

Comment: Take a keyboarding class.  It will do you well in the long term.  You may also want to program keystroke (or keyboard macros) if your IDE supports them.

Comment: To see why macros are evil, try this out: `FOR ("frog", 3.14159)`.

Comment: This is already carried away. Stop it now and use the same C++ language as everybody else.

Comment: Macros are dangerous because arguments can be evaluated more than once... and if they have side effect like calling a function that build a vector, it will perform poorly. **Expert do not wrote such dangerous code.** What do you think `QUICKINSERT(++x, h(++y + g()))` would returns?

Comment: @EJP what do you think defining pb for push_back, mp for make_pair, vi for vector<int> or ull for unsigned long long?

Comment: Regarding your ideas in the light of your last comment: I have the feeling that you want to avoid typing, possibly because you type slowly. Forgive me if this speculation is wrong; but if it is part of your motivation let me assure you: (1) Typing speed is unimportant for the overall performance of a programmer. (2) Speed improves automatically with experience, even if you do not train it specifically (and you could do that if it bothers you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These macro looks like they should be functions.
There are many arguments in comments and I will add one more:
your macro are tied up with naming of variables.

Who is `iQue2`? What is `iSet`?
And what if I want to add `iSet2` and `iQue` and do the same with them?

```
template<typename T>
T accumulate_all(const std::vector<T>& v) {
  return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);
}

template<typename T>
bool queue_if_not_in(std::set<T>& s, std::queue<T>& q, T& val) {
  if (s.find(val) == s.end()) {
    q.push(val);
    s.insert(val);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

You can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177589/invalid-conversion-from-int-to-int-fpermissive) to see, what macro can cause and that compiler cant help in such cases

Comment: what do you think defining pb for push_back, mp for make_pair, etc?

Comment: I cant recomment this for use